# how do i get the content of a chat message in minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am coding a forge minecraft 1.12.2 mod and I need to know how do I get the contents of a chat message that someone sends in chat.

I am using the `ServerChatEvent` event to sence messages but I do not know how to get the actual content of the message itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the message you can use :

```
event.getMessage();
```

Also, if you want the full message (with style/actions/...) you can use :

```java
event.getComponent()
```

More informations:

- [Javadoc](https://skmedix.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs/javadoc/forge/1.9.4-12.17.0.2051/net/minecraftforge/event/ServerChatEvent.html)
- [Few examples](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/net.minecraftforge.event.ServerChatEvent)